# How do I select multiple tooltip-trigger attributes?

Tags: angular, tooltip, uib

I want to make an element show tooltip on tab focus as well as the default `mousenter`. Currently my focus works using `tooltip-trigger="'focus'"`, but now the tooltip only opens on `focus`. I'd like it to also open on `hover` of the element. I'm currently using `uib-tooltip`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a space as the delimiter to each triggering event and **wrap it around single quotes**.  Took me a little bit to realize that single quotes were needed as one of their examples that I was basing off of didn't wrap the attribute value in one.

```
tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter focus'"
```